# Update UI element in Universal Application on Windows-8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a TextBlock on my Windows 8.1 application:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="some" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

And I have a code:

```
some.Text = "example 1";
// working with web service
some.Text = "example 2";
// working with database
```

When I launch my code I see only "example 1" message. The message "example 2" I can see only after database operation complete.

Is there any way on Windows 8.1 to redraw/refresh/update UI element?

**Update:**

Here is database operation:

```
foreach(var record in records)
{
   SqliteController.InsertRecord(record);
}

....

public void async InsertRecord(Inspection record)
{
    connection.InsertAsync(inspection);
}
```

Comment: Are you blocking your UI thread with some heavy job? How your database operation look like?

Comment: I am not sure. I have updated my question. But, yes - it looks like I am blocking UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UI thread seems to be blocked, thus it isn't updeted right away. I've not seen all the code, but from this what you have shown seems that `connection.InsertAsync(inspection);` is an asynchronous operation. Probably in this situation it may be sufficient just to *await* your procedure:

```cs
foreach (var record in records)
{
    await SqliteController.InsertRecord(record);
}
```

You can also think of redirecting heavy job to other thread, for example like this:

```cs
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var record in records)
         SqliteController.InsertRecord(record);
});
```

You may also think of using [Paraller.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx) to speed up your operation.

As for asynchronous programming you will find many usefull information at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Stephen Cleary's blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Thanks, but may be there is any way to say UI thread to update UI control before the database blocking operation starts ?

Comment: UI thread should never be blocked and then UI updates are performed right away. Use asynchronous operations and redirect heavy job to other threads.